# Grails 3 application.yml is different for every developer - how can we externalize differences?

Tags: grails, configuration

So we have application.yml in a grails 3 app.  It has settings like....

```
environments:
    development:
        ourapp:
            bcrypt:
                saltlevel: 4
            url: http://localhost:8080
            media:
                root: /Users/myuser/ourapp/media
```

But these "development" settings will be different for each dev's workstation.  I can easily "not check in" changes to this file but it gets annoying having to stash/unstash changes continuously when switching branches, pulling, merging, etc.

Is there a way to move development specific settings out of this source controlled application.yml file?

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but you could do something like this:

1. Copy `application.yml` to `application.yml.template`
2. Add `application.yml` to `.gitignore`
3. Add a step to your project setup documentation saying 'once you've cloned the project, copy `application.yml.template` to `application.yml`'

We did the same thing with `application.properties` in Grails 2.x - we basically never needed to update the file so it worked well as a solution for us.